# Swift 4 Get preferredUnit from HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I´m a beginner in Swift and I tried to get the User preferred Unit from HealthKit.

Apple offers this function for it

```
func preferredUnits(for quantityTypes: Set<HKQuantityType>, 
     completion: @escaping ([HKQuantityType : HKUnit], Error?) -> Void)
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614172-preferredunits#declarations)

But I really have no idea how to implement it correctly. Atm the function do nothing in my App.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    let bloodGlucose = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)
    let HKQuantitySet: Set<HKSampleType> = [bloodGlucose!]        

    self.preferredUnits(for: HKQuantitySet as! Set<HKQuantityType>, completion: { (preferedUnit, error) in
            print(preferedUnit)
        })

    return true
}



func preferredUnits(for quantityTypes: Set<HKQuantityType>,
                completion: @escaping ([HKQuantityType : HKUnit], Error?) -> Void){

}
```

I´m pretty sure I am totally wrong about this.

Does someone know how to implement the function correctly? Not only for `bloodglucose`, in general, would be nice.

Comment: You implementation looks ok so far.  What do you want to do with the value?  You would probably store it in a property.

Comment: I would store it into the userdefaults. That’s not the problem. The problem is that I do not getting any value or error. The app just do not execute the function. I implemented it into the app delegate file after I get the state of permission.

Comment: You need to show more code in context. How is this code supposed to be called?

Comment: There is no more code. I have no idea how to implement it. But I would like to implement it like the following. 
Executed on Startup, the App detects the user preferred Unit and stores it to the "userdefaults"

Comment: There must be more code. You can just type this code in the middle of your AppDelegate. It must be enclosed in some function. Which function?  How is that function called

Comment: I posted the Code as Answer @Paulw11

Comment: Don't post additional information as an answer; [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50936871/edit) your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173430/discussion-between-paulw11-and-exitare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `preferredUnits` function an instance of `HKHealthStore`.  Your code is just calling a function that you have declared with the same signature that does nothing.